# point multiple domain to single web hosting account

Tags: .htaccess, redirection, 301-redirect

point multiple domain to single web hosting account using htaccess

i have used the following .htaccess file in my public_html directory

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.org$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1.org$  
RewriteRule ^/?$ "/site1.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

directory structure

/public_html/site1.org/welcome.html

if i typed site1.org redirection works perfect but the URL will be http://site1.org/site1.org/welcome.html instead of http://site1.org/welcome.html

and the URL will be SEO Friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky to do without control of the main Apache config, since [Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) are the proper way to do it.

You could probably improve your rewrite solution thus:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.org$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1.org$  
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /site1.org/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess you have written sends a 301 redirect to the browser, which then re-request the page from the url it was directed to. The .htaccess does not serve different content based on the incoming domain.

It would be best to use a PHP script, for example, to detect the domain and send content based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not point multiple domain to single web hosting account using htaccess. Here you are doing url redirection. Please phrase your question properly.

Comment: in my cpanel setup, if i add a new domain pointing this hosting it will create the .htaccess file mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

Mine I have it like this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```